# Why does junction capacitance increase as the depletion width decreases in a diode?

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism

As the depletion width increases, the charge inside the depletion region increases.  Capacitance is the ability to store charge.  As the depletion width increases the capacitance should increase.  Why does the opposite happen?

Comment: What happens if you spread the plates apart in a parallel-plate capacitor?

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, a capacitor with a smaller separation between charges has higher capacity; that's the same for all capacitors.

Comment: No that analogy doesn't make sense at all is not same scenario at all

Comment: Your title says decreases; your words say increases. Choose!

Comment: @mahmoodesmail, Hearth and Marcus Muller are correct.

Comment: It is **not** the charge in the depletion region that determines the capacitance. Only the **size** of the depletion region relates to the capacitance.

Comment: As the reverse bias increases, each additional "*layer*" of charge uncovered is farther away from the centre of the depletion region than before. So moving the plates of a capacitor is a good analogy.

Answer (score 3):

> As the depletion width increases, the charge inside the depletion
> region increases. Capacitance is the **ability to store charge**

The [depletion region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_region) is created by the charge removing free electrons and filling in holes, turning the area into an insulator which cannot store any more charge. As voltage is increased the width gets larger and the capacitance gets smaller due to the increased distance between the 'plates' (conducting areas) reducing the influence that the electric field has over the (wider) gap.

So while the junction does store more charge as reverse bias voltage is increased, the *incremental* ability to store charge (ie. its capacitance) gets less.

This property is put to good use in [varicap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicap) diodes, which are designed to maximize the capacitance variation with bias voltage.

[image]

Comment: i was on focusing on the charge not really the thinking about ability to store more charge decreases thanks that really clear things up

Comment: maybe because its my first time learning about non linear device i am not used in thinking about capacitance in that way btw sorry i cant vote yet

Answer (score 1):

The depletion width increases because the applied voltage increases (and as doping levels decrease).

The depletion width increases with the square root of the voltage, thus the charge 'uncovered' (i.e. the charge in one side of the depletion region) only increases as the square root of the voltage. The incremental capacitance (C=dQ/dV) therefore becomes smaller as the voltage increases.

Comment: thanks I wasn't thinking about it in that way  I was thinking only about charge not about change in charge with respect to voltage maybe because its my first time learning about non linear device i am not used in thinking about capacitance in that way btw sorry i cant vote yet